# how to use Jhipster-jdl without modify the configration i update before?

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

when i create an Entity ,I modify the code in the Entity file .and then I add some fields in the jdl file and import . How can I keep the changes and add the fields in the Entity rather than override or not override.

Comment: Work in a branch using git  and merge, consider JHipster generator as a member of dev team. Get some inspiration about the upgrade generator explanations http://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/

Comment: thanks a lot ,but I mean I use import-jdl to create an entity ,and I modify the entity class directly. then I add some fields in the jdl file and import,it will make my changes when I modify the entity class directly restore

Comment: My comment still applies

Comment: Is it? Let me think it over ,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should use version control likes git and then generate. After that you can merge, revert, etc. For more information visit [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/)